# CMake execute archiver for each object separately

Tags: cmake, unix-ar

I want to create a library with a archiver (from arduino, esp8266) in cmake.

```
add_library(arduino_core STATIC ${CORE_ASM_ITEMS} ${CORE_C_ITEMS} ${CORE_CXX_ITEMS})
```

These options I have set, specially the CMAKE_AR

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "${TOOLCHAIN_BIN}/${TARGET_TRIPLET}-gcc${SYSTEM_EXTENSION}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "${TOOLCHAIN_BIN}/${TARGET_TRIPLET}-g++${SYSTEM_EXTENSION}")
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER "${TOOLCHAIN_BIN}/${TARGET_TRIPLET}-gcc${SYSTEM_EXTENSION}")
set(CMAKE_AR "${TOOLCHAIN_BIN}/${TARGET_TRIPLET}-ar${SYSTEM_EXTENSION}")

SET(CMAKE_CXX_ARCHIVE_CREATE "<CMAKE_AR> cru <TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>")
SET(CMAKE_C_ARCHIVE_CREATE "<CMAKE_AR> cru <TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>")
```

If I build this library with make, it will execute:

```
/Users/XXX/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-3-20ed2b9/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-ar cru libarduino_core.a  CMakeFiles/arduino_core.dir/Users/XXX/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.0/cores/esp8266/cont.S.o CMakeFiles/arduino_core.dir/Users/XXX/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.0/cores/esp8266/StackThunk.c.o
```

And much more objects at the end (about 60). But I think the archiver doesn't want this syntax. If I link this built library at the end, it fails because of undefined references.

But if I built the library manually, giving each object an own archiver execution, like the following, the linking of the library at the end is successful.

```
/Users/XXX/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-3-20ed2b9/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-ar cru libarduino_core.a CMakeFiles/arduino_core.dir/Users/XXX/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.0/cores/esp8266/cont.S.o
/Users/XXX/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-3-20ed2b9/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-ar cru libarduino_core.a CMakeFiles/arduino_core.dir/Users/XXX/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.0/cores/esp8266/StackThunk.c.o
...
```

So my question: Is there any CMake option to limit for example the amount of given objects? Or anything like that?

Comment: "But I think the archiver doesn't want this syntax." - The syntax with multiple object files should be perfectly for an archiver. Probably, the reason of "undefined references"  is somewhere else.

Comment: @Tsyvarev yeah ok you're right, it was my fault. Found out that after this library was built, cmake automatically executes "ranlib" from OS, which corrupts the library. I changed "CMAKE_RANLIB" to right binary.